# How to check if list element exists in TCL?

Tags: list, tcl, exists

Say I have a TCL list, and I have append some elements to my list. Now I want to check if I have appended 6 or 7 elements.

In order to check if list element exists in the place specified by an index I have used:

```
if { [info exists [lindex $myList 6]] } {
#if I am here then I have appended 7 elems, otherwise it should be at least 6
}
```

But seams this does not work. How I should do that? properly? It is OK to check **if { [lindex $myList 6]] eq "" }**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I found this question because I wanted to check if a list *contains a specific item*, rather than just checking the list's length.

To see if an element exists within a list, use the [`lsearch`](http://www.astro.princeton.edu/~rhl/Tcl-Tk_docs/tcl/lsearch.n.html) function:

```
if {[lsearch -exact $myList 4] >= 0} {
    puts "Found 4 in myList!"
}
```

The `lsearch` function returns the index of the first found element or `-1` if the given element wasn't found. Through the `-exact`, `-glob` (which is the default) or `-regexp` options, the type of pattern search can be specified.

Answer (score 18):

Why don't you use `llength` to check the length of your list:

```
if {[llength $myList] == 6} {
    # do something
}
```

Of course, if you want to check the element at a specific index, then then use `lindex` to retrieve that element and check that. e.g. `if {[lindex $myList 6] == "something"}`

Your code using the `info exists` is not working, because the `info exists` command checks if a variable exists. So you are basically checking if there is a variable whose name equals the value returned by `[lindex $myList 6]`.

Comment: What you mean my "something"? I have used if { [lindex $myList 6]] eq "" } in order to check if the 7th elem exist. If it does not exist, I am in the body of the if statement. Is it recommended to use?

Comment: "something" is just a random string I chose for my example. You can of course replace that with any string you like. The `if {[lindex $myList 6]] == ""}` will most likely work, but it does have a flaw. Suppose you have the following list: `set l {1 2 3 4 5 6 ""}`. This list has 7 elements (check the output of `llength $l`). But your code would treat this list as if it only had 6 elements. If you want to check if an element exists at index `X`, use `llength` to check if the list is that long, it's definitely more explicit. If you wan't to check if the element has a specific value use `lindex`.

Comment: Its worth noting that the solution the OP is using ([lindex $mylist 6]) isn't semantically equivalent to the question he's trying to ask (does this list have 6 elements). I'm a big proponent of code expressing what it's trying to accomplish. The answer posted here by überjesus ([llength $mylist] == 6) expresses the question that's actually being asked so, even if both worked correctly, this would be the better option.

Answer (score 7):

Another way to check for existence in a list in TCL is to simply use 'in', for instance:

```
if {"4" in $myList} {
    puts "Found 4 in my list"
}
```

It's slightly cleaner/more readable!

Comment: When did TCL become Python !